# Error in updating data frame based off another value

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

```
Test3 <- function(n,d) {

  die1 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
  die2 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
  move = die1 + die2
  position_before_roll = move
  position_after_roll = move
  jail = move


  monopoly_sim = data.frame(position_before_roll,die1,die2,move,position_after_roll,jail)
  monopoly_sim[1,1]=0

  i = 1
for(i in 1:n){
  #Needs to be position after roll + Dice Roll (Move)

  monopoly_sim[i,5] = monopoly_sim[i,1] + monopoly_sim[i,4]
  monopoly_sim[i+1,1] = monopoly_sim[i,5] 
}
i=1
  for(i in 1:n) {

    if (monopoly_sim[i,1] + monopoly_sim[1,4] >= 39) {
      monopoly_sim[i,5] =  0 + monopoly_sim[i,1] + monopoly_sim[i,4] - 39
      monopoly_sim[i+1, 1] = monopoly_sim[i,5]
      }  

    else {
    monopoly_sim[i,5] = monopoly_sim[i,1] + monopoly_sim[i,4]
    monopoly_sim[i+1, 1] = monopoly_sim[i,5]
    }
  }

  i=1
    for (i in 1:n) {
      if (monopoly_sim[i,2] == monopoly_sim[i,3] && monopoly_sim[i+1,2] == monopoly_sim[i+1,3] 
      && monopoly_sim[i+2,2] == monopoly_sim[i+2,3] && monopoly_sim[i+3,2] != monopoly_sim[i+3,3])
      {monopoly_sim[i+2,6] = "Yes" }  
      else {monopoly_sim[i+2,6] = "No"}
         }

  return(monopoly_sim)

  }

df = Test3(200,6)
x1= as.data.frame(df)
```

Here is my code. The goal of the function is to create a data frame and populate the values accordingly. Based off start position being 0 and then adding dice roll 1 and dice roll 2.

I have gotten position_before_roll to equal (position_after_roll of the previous row). However, where I am struggling is that I want my "board" to have 39 positions, so after it would go to a position great than 39, it instead loops back around. To try and do this I set it to after being greater than 39 subtract 39 from it.

When i look at my output DF though it is not always doing that. It is instead subtracting at values sometimes less than 39 thus creating negative numbers.

Comment: as a general comment, you may find it easier to code if you don't always use `i` as a variable in your loops. You can use anything you like (e.g. `j`) and that helps when you have multiple loops.

Answer (score 0):

I dug into your code and, as far as it seems, you are trying to simulate the Monopoly game. Next time, please, provide some context and describe what are you trying to do with your code, especially in this case rules that you were trying to implement.
I changed all variable references so the code became more readable and friendly. I also removed one cycle and inserted the check for `i > 39` inside the first cycle. Some variables are initiated as NAs and they are calculated on-the-go. Still, these are just brief improvements and there is still a lot to do to make it perfect. Please have a look:

```
monopoly_sim <- function(n,d) {

#n <- 200
#d <- 6

die1 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
die2 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
move = die1 + die2


df = data.frame(position_before_roll = NA, die1, die2, move, position_after_roll = NA, jail = "No", stringsAsFactors = F)
df$position_before_roll[1] = 0

for(i in 1:n){
  # Simulate rolling dice and moving 
  df$position_after_roll[i] = df$position_before_roll[i] + df$move[i]

  # If position after roll greater than 38, substract 39 from it
  if (df$position_after_roll[i] >=39) {df$position_after_roll[i] <- df$position_after_roll[i] - 39}

  # Calculate start position on the next move
  if (i < n ) {df$position_before_roll[i+1] = df$position_after_roll[i]}


}

# Check if move should lead to the jail
for (i in 1:n-3) {
if (df$die1[i] == df$die2[i] &&
    df$die1[i+1] == df$die2[i+1] &&
    df$die1[i+2] == df$die2[i+2] &&
    df$die1[i+3] != df$die2[i+3])
  {df$jail[i+2] = "Yes" }  
  else {df$jail[i+2] = "No"}
}
return(df)
}


df <- monopoly_sim(200,6)

head(df, 40)

   position_before_roll die1 die2 move position_after_roll jail
1                     0    6    4   10                  10   No
2                    10    2    4    6                  16   No
3                    16    5    6   11                  27   No
4                    27    4    2    6                  33   No
5                    33    2    5    7                   1   No
6                     1    5    3    8                   9   No
7                     9    3    6    9                  18   No
8                    18    3    6    9                  27   No
9                    27    5    6   11                  38   No
10                   38    5    6   11                  10   No
11                   10    5    3    8                  18   No
12                   18    6    2    8                  26   No
13                   26    3    3    6                  32   No
14                   32    5    1    6                  38   No
15                   38    1    4    5                   4   No
16                    4    3    6    9                  13   No
17                   13    6    6   12                  25   No
18                   25    3    5    8                  33   No
19                   33    5    5   10                   4   No
20                    4    1    6    7                  11   No
21                   11    3    6    9                  20   No
22                   20    1    4    5                  25   No
23                   25    4    6   10                  35   No
24                   35    4    4    8                   4   No
25                    4    5    4    9                  13   No
26                   13    1    1    2                  15   No
27                   15    1    6    7                  22   No
28                   22    6    1    7                  29   No
29                   29    1    2    3                  32   No
30                   32    5    3    8                   1   No
31                    1    6    6   12                  13   No
32                   13    6    6   12                  25   No
33                   25    4    1    5                  30   No
34                   30    1    6    7                  37   No
35                   37    6    4   10                   8   No
36                    8    3    4    7                  15   No
37                   15    4    1    5                  20   No
38                   20    5    1    6                  26   No
39                   26    5    5   10                  36   No
40                   36    3    6    9                   6   No
```